# finite signed measure on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying for a qualifying exam and I'm stuck with the following question from an old exam; any help would be greatly appreciated: is there a finite signed measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $ \int x^n d\mu (x) = e^{-\pi^2}$ for every $n=1,2,...$?

Comment: Try a point mass

Comment: What about the same question  on [1/2,3/2]??

Comment: @AntonioAlfieri On the interval $[1/2,2/3]$ there is no such $\mu$. Because in that case $\left|\int x^n\,d\mu\right|\le c\sup_x|x^n|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mu$ defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$, in the following way: $\mu(A)=e^{-\pi^2}$ if $1\in A$  and $\mu(A)=0$ if $1\notin A$.

It is easy to prove that $\mu$ is finite measure (and so a finite signed measure) and $ \int x^n d\mu (x) = e^{-\pi^2}$ for every $n=1,2,...$